# php application went red aws beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a PHP application which goes RED while deployment to Elstic BeanStalk. I simply zip my app folder and upload it. Do I need to check/change anything over here.

I urgently need this app to be working. Would really appreciate if any one could look into it or provide me some pointers to solve the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the latter, it should work just fine because the contents of the zip will simply unpack in the document root.

If it's the former, and the entire directory is unpacking in the document root, you'll need to update your document_root setting in the console to point to the name of the directory.

thanks Hope this might solve your probs.